# Математическое дизассемблирование

Tags: ассемблер, математика

Часто в последнее время приходится сталкиваться с решением сложных уравнений в процессе дизассемблирования. Вот, например:

```
0x926D*a - 0x5475*b - 0x752*c - 0xB4C1*d + 0xC5C9*e + 0xA89E*f + 0x7372*g + 0x4004*h + 0xE15D*i + 0x3922*j + 0x5262*k + 0x99AE*l + 0xD5E5*m = 0x1468753
```

И это еще далеко не самое сложное.
Может быть есть какие-либо способы более быстрого решения подобной мути?

Comment: Что ж вы такое реверсите?..

Answer (score 5):

Если переменные a, b, c, ...—целые числа, эта "муть" называется линейным [диофантовым уравнением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). [Матиясевич](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87,_%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) доказал, что в общем случае, алгоритмического разрешения для таких уравнений—нет.